# Array length empty

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and jquery, trying to learn, here I have this code to push values into the array, when I tried use `length` it shows me 0.

I know that there is guide out there, but still I don't understand what it actually means, can anyone help me out?

```
$.ajax({
            url : "pokemonlist.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            var arr = lines[i].split('"');

            pokemon_id = arr[1];
            pokemon_img = arr[3];
            pokemon_name = arr[4];
            pokemon_name = pokemon_name.trim()

            pokemon_array.push([ pokemon_id, pokemon_img, pokemon_name ]);
        }
            }
        });

    console.log(pokemon_array.length);
```

Comment: console.log is outside the $.ajax call, so it occurs before success function completes. Try `setTimeout(function(){console.log(pokemon_array.length); }, 1000);` or move the console log inside the success function, at the end.

Comment: timeout is not a solution, it is just a test and I suggested it just to see what will happen so that it is more clear to MuthaFury how all this works :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `console.log(pokemon_array.length)` outside of the `success` callback, so it's actually called before the ajax call is done.

Answer (score -1):

Here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Read about `success` and `complete` parameters.

Simple example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my-mega-link',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13377759)

Comment: @dakab But documentation is the best answer for simple questions :(

Comment: Sure it is. But if the documentation isn't available, it renders a link-only answer useless. Prociding a simple example  (like the one [you added](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39013761/revisions)) makes it much more helpful.

Comment: @dakab okay I will remember this advice :)